How to make bottom tool window to fill entire bottom right?
I want to fill the bottom tool window to the entire bottom right as shown in the yellow box.
I tried unchecking Widescreen tool window layout from setting but it fills the entire bottom width making my device emulator smaller, which is a side effect I don't want.

